# Zend Framework multiplay forms

Tags: forms, zend-framework

I want get the follow thing working.

I've a page with a couple of text articles, each article has his own 'id' in the database. Below every article I want to make it possible to discuss about it. So I setup a discuss form witch I print with my article trough a 'foreach'.

In the form I added a Zend_Form_Element_Hidden. In the view I want to set the value of the hidden field with 'article_id', this likes me the best way to put it in the database?

In the foreach I try the follow thing but when I do this, the form is gone and I only get the element where I add the value.

My code in the view:

foreach ($this->paginator as $article):

```
    echo $this->form->getElement('article')->setValue($article['id']);
```

endforeach;

I hope some one can make this a bit more clear for me :)

With kind regards,

Nicky

Comment: I have read this question a few times and still don't understand the problem. Can you add some more details please?

Comment: Is $this->form->getElement('article') your hidden element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you want to print the form inside the loop but only the element is being printed.

If that is your problem, the reason is because `setValue()` returns the element and not the form.

```
// Your Code
// This will only print the element and not the entire form
echo $this->form->getElement('article')->setValue($article['id']);
```

You will have to change your code to:

```
// Set the element value first
$this->form->getElement('article')->setValue($article['id']);
// Then render the form
echo $this->form;
```

Comment: Thats what I did wrong. Thank u very much :) It's working now!